# How to map one dataframe values to all other dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, group-by, apply

how to get below output, assigned all the 2nd dataframe values.

```
df_left = pd.DataFrame({
    "Id": [1, 2, 3],
    "Value": ["A", "B", "C"]
})

df_right = pd.DataFrame({
    "IdDate": [101, 201, 301, 401, 501],
})

output = pd.DataFrame({
    "Id": [1,1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 ],
    "Value": ["A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C" ],
    "IdDate":[101, 201, 301, 401, 501,101, 201, 301, 401, 501,101, 201, 301, 401, 501 ]
})
```

Comment: `df_left.merge(df_right, how='cross')`

Comment: Using python 3.6..cross is not supported.

Comment: What matters is the pandas version. If you can't update, add a column with all `1` in both dataframes and merge on that.